# CSS Translate/Animation conflict on Safari refresh

Tags: css, safari, jquery-animate, transform, translate

I'm trying to run an animation on an infinite loop, starting when the page loads. Everything works fine until you hit refresh while viewing on Safari on both Mobile and Desktop.

The first time the page loads everything works just fine, it's on refresh when the translate property fails. If I remove the animation, CSS Translate works fine.

The animation goes like this (and I did try using the -webkit- prefix but it won't work).

```
@keyframes circulo_claro { 
    50% {transform: translate(-43%,45%) rotate(8deg);},
    100% {transform: translate(-43%,45%) rotate(0deg);} 
}

@keyframes circulo_naranja { 
    to {transform: translate(-43%,45%) rotate(0deg);} 
}
```

This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/r8wcLLfb/3/

Comment: Refresh should restart the animation...why wouldn't it?

Comment: It should and it does, that's not the problem. The svgs are not suposed to change position (their translate values are always the same), just rotate. When you hit refresh, both circles fly to the center of the screen instead of staying put on the bottom left corner.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have encountered it now.

Comment: The client asked for something different so I didn't need to. This remains unsolved.

Comment: Ok, gutted to find this out. Thanks for getting back to me.